# Can I know which child class am I from parent's code in Moose?

Tags: perl, oop, perl-module, moose

I am creating a set of small Perl programs which will be run like a CLI. I want all of them to share some features, eg. same input/output format (probably JSON). I also want each component to be black-box testable with mock arguments. This is what I have so far:

- A number of modules `actionA.pm`, `actionB.pm`... `actionZZZ.pm`, one for each component/operation. All of them will `use Moose` and should have a `sub run {...}` which will receive a data hasref/object with the operation's input parameters, and any handle (database, filesystem, whatever) they need to use, and return a data hashref/object with the operation's output parameters.
- A Moose role which `requires 'run'` and is consumed by every `actionX.pm` module, forcing them to implement `run`.
- Additional Moose roles and/or superclasses for certain subsets of the `actionX.pm` modules, so they can consume them to specify wether they need their `run` method to be provided with a database handler, a filesystem handler, etc.
- A common Moose superclass (don't know if this really needs to be either Moose nor a superclass, just want this to be a fairly simple one-liner on each `actionX.pm`), let's call it `abstractAction.pm`, for all of the `actionX.pm` classes, which converts them into some sort of Modulino (see below).

What I want to achieve with this is that, when I run `perl actionX.pm arguments` from command line, some code in `abstractAction.pm` will:

1. Read JSON/whatever from `@ARGV` and convert it to Perl data structures.
2. This part is not clear: know that it was called from/as `actionX`, so it knows that if `actionX` consumes role `needDB`, it will need to get a database handler to pass it to `run`, etc.
3. Call `actionX->run()` passing the data object and any handler obtained at step 2.

---

I tried using both `run()` and `__PACKAGE__->run()` in `abstractAction.pm`, but it calls the superclass method, not the child's. Is there any way I can know the child's package name from the parent? That doesn't even sound good. Is there a better way to do what I am trying to achieve?

I know I could simply do `perl abstractAction.pm actionX arguments` instead of `perl actionX.pm arguments` and call it a day, but I'd rather not.

Comment: Your question title and the body of the post don't really fit together. Please try to make it more clear what your actual question is. Also note that in Perl package names are typically written in camel case with a capital first letter. `ActionA.pm` would be correct. I would go with `Action.pm` as the base class and `Action::A`, `Action::B` and so on for the actual action classes. You might also want to take a look at https://metacpan.org/release/MooseX-App.

Comment: @simbabque: I changed the question title, I hope now it fits better. You're right about the naming convention. This is not actual code, I just made example names up as I was writing.

Comment: @simbabque I already looked at MooseX::App and CLI::Framework, but it looks to me that these are good for writing one program with many commands. I need to write many separate programs with just one (implicit) command each, even if they all share some code.

Answer (score 1):

Fundamentally, you'll need to call `run` as a method, using the name of the child class (if it's a class method) or an object of the child class (if it's an instance method) as the invocant.

Calling `run` as a class method:

```
ActionX->run(...)
```

Calling `run` as an instance method:

```
ActionX->new(...)->run(...)
```

---

The other issue is that you're executing a `.pm` file, which leads to problems. Load modules, don't execute them. For example,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $action = shift(@ARGV)
   or die("usage\n");

$action =~ /^\w+\z/
   or die("Bad action\n");

my $pkg = $action;   # Or: my $pkg = "...::" . $action;

my $module =~ s{::}{/}g . '.pm';
require $module;

$pkg->new(@ARGV)->run();
```

If the script is named `action`, then you can do

```
action ActionX parameters
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @ikegami. As I stated in the last paragraph of the question, I'd rather not have the action name passed as a parameter. I'd prefer getting the action name from the module which is being executed.

Comment: Look again. The parameter is the name of the module. Instead of `perl actionX.pm arguments`, use `action actionX arguments`.